# Saving data in parse to a not yet existing user

Tags: parse-platform, email

I am new at programming. I am building sort of like an chat app and I am using Parse as a backend. I want to make it possible for an existing user to send a message to a non existing user if the user knows the non existing-users email. The non-existing user will then get notified by the app on his email that this person send him a message and that he needs to sign up to read the message, and here is the question:

Does Parse makes it possible to chain this message to the non-existing users email, so that when he signs up in the app with this specific email the specific message to this email will display?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you delegating this task to parse then? Just send the email from App with invitation URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, not exactly.

You can create the user with the appropriate e-mail address and a made up password. Once that user exists (and hence is saved) you can start to associate things with it. After that you can send an e-mail to the prospective new user allowing them to complete the registration (this is basically a password reset).